# Not able to load mbtiles in ArcGIS runtime SDK

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase, ios, arcgis-runtime-sdk-ios

I'm not able to load **mbtiles** in any layer using arcgis runtime sdk version 100.1 for iOS. Is it possible to do that in new version of run time sdk. In old runtime SDK, I have used `AGSTiledServiceLayer` to load mbtiles in version 10.2 and now can load only **tpk** files using `AGSArcGISTiledLayer`.

Comment: Was this ever answered, as I am having similar issues.

Comment: I have used `AGSImageTiledLayer` to load mbtiles (sqlite database)

Comment: I am looking to solve this I am using .NET caro